# How can I add a time function then click a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am building a website for my school and I just finished a slideshow. To change between pictures on the slideshow a user is required to click the forward or previous button. Is their something that I can add to make it automatically move forward to the next slide every 5 seconds?

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      * {box-sizing: border-box}
      body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
      .mySlides {display: none} 
      img {vertical-align: middle;}

      /* Slideshow container */
      .slideshow-container {
        max-width: 1000px;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
      }

      /* Next & previous buttons */
      .prev, .next {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: auto;
        padding: 16px;
        margin-top: -22px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 18px;
        transition: 0.6s ease;
        border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
        user-select: none;
      }

      /* Position the "next button" to the right */
      .next {
        right: 0;
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
      }

      /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
      .prev:hover, .next:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      }


      /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
      .numbertext {
        color: #f2f2f2;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
      }

      /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
      .dot {
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 15px;
        width: 15px;
        margin: 0 2px;
        background-color: #bbb;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
      }

      .active, .dot:hover {
        background-color: #717171;
      }

      /* Fading animation */
      .fade {
        -webkit-animation-name: fade;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
        animation-name: fade;
        animation-duration: 1.5s;
      }

      @-webkit-keyframes fade {
        from {opacity: .4} 
        to {opacity: 1}
      }
    
      @keyframes fade {
        from {opacity: .4} 
        to {opacity: 1}
      }
    
      /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
      @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
        .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
 
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    </div>
    <br>

    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
    </div>

    <script>
      var slideIndex = 1;
      showSlides(slideIndex);

      function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
      }

      function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
      }

      function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I just need to move to the next slide every 5 seconds

Comment: They have examples on this page. - https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `setInterval` which runs the function specified at given `timeinterval`.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
var timeGap = 5000; // time gap in milliseconds
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

setInterval(function() {
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  slideIndex++
}, timeGap)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
      margin: 0
    }
    
    .mySlides {
      display: none
    }
    
    img {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    /* Slideshow container */
    
    .slideshow-container {
      max-width: 1000px;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
    }
    /* Next & previous buttons */
    
    .prev,
    .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: auto;
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: -22px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 18px;
      transition: 0.6s ease;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
    }
    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    
    .next {
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }
    /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
    
    .prev:hover,
    .next:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
    /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
    
    .numbertext {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }
    /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
    
    .dot {
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      margin: 0 2px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    }
    
    .active,
    .dot:hover {
      background-color: #717171;
    }
    /* Fading animation */
    
    .fade {
      -webkit-animation-name: fade;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
      animation-name: fade;
      animation-duration: 1.5s;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes fade {
      from {
        opacity: .4
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes fade {
      from {
        opacity: .4
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }
    /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
      .prev,
      .next,
      .text {
        font-size: 11px
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

  </div>
  <br>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` to call a particular function every few secondas and in that function you can move slide to next page. Something like:

```
function myFunc() {
   if (lastSlide) {
      clearInterval(slideMoveInterval); // <- clean up
   } else {
      goToNextSlide();
   }
}

let slideMoveInterval = setInterval(myFunc, 5000); // <- called every 5 seconds
```

I have excluded functions but you can replace psuedo code with your functions.

MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 0):

You may use the javascript API `setInterval`() as below. This will invoke the `call_AnyFunction_Here` function every 3 seconds.

```
setInterval(function(){ call_AnyFunction_Here() }, 3000);
```

Put your slide navigation function in place of this function